# LocalDate.toDate( ) returns inaccurate date

Tags: java, android, date, jodatime

I am using JODA for formatting a Date of type : 2012-01-05T08:00:00.000Z (For the date 5th of Jan 2012) and trying to convert it to a Java Date.

The following are the steps which I am taking at this stage:

- Using the DateTimeFormatter to do the initial formatting:

  ```
  DateTimeFormatter jodaParser = DateTimeFormat
                              .forPattern(inputDateWhichIsAString);
  ```
- Converting it to a LocalDate with the necessary Time Zone (UTC)

  ```
  LocalDate localDate = jodaParser
                              .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
                              .parseDateTime(inputDateWhichIsAString).toLocalDate();
  ```
- Using the LocalDate to retrieve the Java Date object

  ```
  return localDate.toDate();
  ```

However while I should expect the returned date to be : 5th of Jan 2012, what I am getting is 1st of Jan 1970. I was under the impression that JODA takes care of these problems which the Java Date object is known to have.

Am I doing something wrong here - or do anyone of you have had similar issues and know a workaround to it?

Thanks 
Rajat

Edit:

Firstly thanks Michael.

So here is an improvement over my previous snippet which has made sure that I get the right Date - in other words the solution.

```
 
    //Make sure you use HH instead of hh if you are using 24 hour convention. I use this convention since my date format is: 2012-01-05T08:00:00.000Z


     DateTimeFormatter jodaParser = 
                 DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");

     LocalDate date = jodaParser.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).parseDateTime
                 (inputDateWhichIsAString).toLocalDate();

     return date.toDate();
```

Cheers 
Rajat

Comment: +1 For the cruel naming-convention blubWhichIsAString :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTimeFormat.forPattern` expects, as the name suggests, a pattern instead of an input to convert from. Only DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(String) expects the String to parse the actual data.

So in DateTimeFormat.forPattern's String you have to pass a formatstring. Depending on your input, use the formatting symbols described here: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Since we all like shorter solutions :

Considering my date format is one of type ISODateFormat as defined by JODA a much simpler solution to my problem would be :

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
DateTime dateTime = fmt.parseDateTime(inputDateWhichIsAString);
if (dateTime != null) {
    Date date = dateTime.toDate();
}
return date;
```

Comment: Please ensure your code is formatted and viewed correctly thus it stays both easy to read and follow. I didn't test the code but one can clearly see that 'date' is not defined in the line the return statement stands.